# Codename one Form layout not folding when keyboard displayed

Tags: android, ios, layout, keyboard, codenameone

I'm having an issue with an app I'm working on an app that features a chat page.
The main form layout is a border layout with something in the north and a text field in the south, and the chat messages in the center.
When the text field is focused and the keyboard appears the layout shifts upward off the screen instead of resizing.
I'm fairly sure this used to work on older versions of CN1.
The center container with the messages is scroll-able Y.
I've reproduced this with a minimal form that only contains a single text area in the south, and the title area is still pushed off the screen when the keyboard appears.
I've been testing on android but the problem is also seen on iOS.

EDIT:
Here's a minimal example of the issue;

```
Form hi = new Form("Welcome", new BorderLayout());

hi.add(BorderLayout.NORTH, new Label("Top"));

Container c = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
c.setScrollableY(true);
hi.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, c);

hi.add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, new TextField());
hi.show();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug has now been [fixed](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/commit/7cbaccffd63126e805a6f0dcd2ab93cbd0f61761).  It will be available in the next server update.  You shouldn't need to make any changes to your code.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the content in the center has `setScrollableY(true)` make sure it's the only scrollable element in the UI.

Comment: As I said above my center container has scrollableY set to true.  
Still not working even on the very simplest example form.  
I can put together a minimal example if that helps

Comment: Can you check out if the Dr. Sbaitso demo works for you? If not this is probably a regression which means filing an issue. If it does work then see what we did differently there in comparison to your code.

Comment: Folding now only works if you set  hi.setFormBottomPaddingEditingMode(true);  
I'm fairly sure this wasn't the case in the past (when the center was scrollable y)

Comment: This might have worked in the past on Android but there are some edge cases that are really hard to deal with when it comes to keyboard input

Answer (score 0):

use:
`hi.setFormBottomPaddingEditingMode(true);`

Where "hi" is the form you want to have folding.